# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument. Angular By JS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the error of angular "Error: ng:areq Bad Argument", the thing here is that if I put the javascript code directly in the html, as bellow, there is no mistake and it works, but when the same code is called from another file then is where the error appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="aplicacion" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cuestionarios y así</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var aplicacion = angular.module('aplicacion', []);

            aplicacion.controller('cuestionacio', function($scope, $http, $document) {

                $scope.preguntas = [];

                $scope.cargaCuestionario = function(){
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET', 
                        url: 'http://localhost:8000/serv/pregunticas/?format=json'

                    }).
                    success(function(data) {
                        console.log('ESto');
                        console.log(datos);
                    }).
                    error(function(datos) {
                        console.log(datos);
                        alert('Error obtienedo el cuestionario');
                    });
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="cuestionacio" ng-init="cargaCuestionario()">
            <div ng-repeat="item in preguntas">
                <p>{{item.pregunta}}</p>
                <br>
                <div ng-if="{{item.tipo}}">
                    <select ng-repeat>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>calendario</p>
                <br>
                <p>mapa</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks
P.S. Sorry for the horrible english.

Comment: Are you sure you are including that `js` file?

Comment: what do you mean by called from another file?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because there is no 404 error when I use it.